# how to validate multiple textbox using foreach loop in mvc?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
 <div class="container" id="editdirector">             
            <table id="tblEdit1" class="table table-hover table-bordered" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                <thead style="text-align: center;">
                    <tr>                        
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Mobile</th>
                        <th>Email</th>                        
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody style="text-align: center; text-transform:uppercase"> 
                    @int count; 
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Directors)
{
                        
        <tr class="item1">
            <td hidden>
                <input type="hidden" class="id1" name="" id="ID" value="@item.ID" />
            </td>
            <td>
                
                    
                <input type="text" class="name1" id="txtName" value="@item.Dir_Name" onchange="DirectorValidation();" style=" text-transform uppercase">
                
            </td>
            <td>
                

                <input type="text" class="mobile1" id="txtMobile" value="@item.Dir_Mobile" onchange="DirectorValidation();">
                
            </td>
            <td>
                

                <input type="text" class="email1" id="txtEmail" value="@item.Dir_Email" onchange="DirectorValidation();" style="text-transform: uppercase">
                
            </td>
                
        </tr>         
                    }                
                </tbody>
             
            </table>
                <button type="button" id="AddGrid" class="btn btn-default" style="border-radius: 20px; background: #59980c; color: #ffffff; margin-bottom: 20px;">
                    Update Director
                </button>
        </div>
```

I want to put JavaScript validation on all row generated from foreach loop but it will only validate first row not second or third row and here is the code for that

```
function DirectorValidation() {

  if ($('#txtMobile').val() == "") {
    alert('Enter Mobile No.');
    $('#txtMobile').focus();
    return false;
  }

  if ($('#txtMobile').val() != "") {
    var mobilePattern = /^([6-9]\d{9})$/;
    if (!$('#txtMobile').val().match(mobilePattern)) {
      alert('Invalid Mobile No.');
      $('#txtMobile').focus();
      return false;
    }
  }


  if ($('#txtEmail').val().trim() == "") {
    alert('Please Enter Email.');
    $('#txtEmail').focus();
    return false;
  }

  if ($('#txtEmail').val() != "") {
    var emailPattern = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    if (!$('#txtEmail').val().match(emailPattern)) {
      alert('Invalid Email Id.');
      $('#txtEmail').focus();
      return false;
    }
  }

}
```

This validate only first row and not the second row. How I can validate?

Comment: `id` must be unique so why it's validate first row not all, use `class` instead of  `id` to validate.

Comment: @shubham raut: It's more reasonable to applying [validation attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to your model class.

Comment: Thanks @jackdaw for your suggestion but I also have 30 fields on which I apply model validation but for some reason I only need JavaScript validation.

Comment: @Shree I tried with class but still same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Generate dynamic ID of each control in table

Step 2: Set onblur or leave javascript event

Step 3: Create function for Mobile Pattern and Email Pattern Check

Step 4: Check value is empty or not in these Pattern function

Step 5: Call function in onblur event or leave event

Please check below code I hope it is work

```
<div class="container" id="editdirector">             
    <table id="tblEdit1" class="table table-hover table-bordered" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <thead style="text-align: center;">
            <tr>                        
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Mobile</th>
                            <th>Email</th>                        
            </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody style="text-align: center; text-transform:uppercase"> 
            @int count; 
            @foreach (var item in Model.Directors)
            {
                <tr class="item1">
                    <td hidden>
                        <input type="hidden" class="id1" name="" id="ID" value="@item.ID" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="name1" id="txtName_@count" value="@item.Dir_Name" style=" text-transform uppercase">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="mobile1" id="txtMobile_@count" value="@item.Dir_Mobile" onblur="CheckMobileNo(this.id);">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="email1" id="txtEmail_@count" value="@item.Dir_Email" onchange="CheckEmail(this.id);" style="text-transform: uppercase">
                    </td>
                </tr>         
            }                
                </tbody>
    </table>
        <button type="button" id="AddGrid" class="btn btn-default" style="border-radius: 20px; background: #59980c; color: #ffffff; margin-bottom: 20px;">Update Director</button>
</div>

function CheckMobileNo(id)
{
    if ($('#' + id).val() == "") 
    {
            alert('Enter Mobile No.');
            $('#' + id).focus();
            return false;
    }
    else if ($('#' + id).val() != "") 
    {
        var mobilePattern = /^([6-9]\d{9})$/;

        if (!$('#' + id).val().match(mobilePattern)) 
        {
        alert('Invalid Mobile No.');
        $('#' + id).focus();
        return false;
        }
    }
}

function CheckEmail(id)
{
    if ($('#' + id).val().trim() == "") 
    {
        alert('Please Enter Email.');
        $('#' + id).focus();
        return false;
    }

    if ($('#' + id).val() != "") 
    {
        var emailPattern = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
        if (!$('#' + id).val().match(emailPattern)) 
        {
            alert('Invalid Email Id.');
            $('#' + id).focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will check now.

Comment: Thanks @Hardik Your solution is perfectly worked for me. Just I need to increment the count after closing tr for id increment. Once again thank you so much.